# uname -r command showing nothing in my system?

Tags: linux, rhel

I am running a script to grep kernel version

```
 /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

but getting output as

```
 /lib/modules//build.
```

Also when I tried to hit a command uname -r it is showing nothing, this is happening only when I am running the script and after that uname -r will showing nothing.

```
[root ~]# uname -r

[root ~]#
```

I have rhel 4.10.0.305 kernel version

Also I am getting FATAL:kernel too old error.

Comment: You are attempting to run a program called `shell` that does not exist. What has `grep` got to do with this? Where and when is the `kernel too old` occurring? If you have a root prompt, then obviously kernel loaded. The likely problem is that the version of glib is too **new** for that kernel -- it uses syscalls NYI in that kernel.

Comment: Can we use current glib in my system with that old kernel? I don't want to update kernel

Comment: ??? This link is mine

Comment: My bad -- I found something helpful from google "kernel too old" but hit the wrong link. Nevertheless, if you want to stick with kernel 4.10 then you need to install an earlier glibc, which you may have to compile yourself. `ldd --version` top line shows you what you have. There are compatibility tables around online. I found "Most distros configure the build of libc to only be compatible with kernels from a specified minimal kernel version onwards. For glibc, that is set using its configure script's --enable-kernel=VERSION option.".